# Meteor 1.5.2.2 - "Only one default export allowed per module" error

Tags: reactjs, meteor

While running this code it shows me this error:

> Only one default export allowed per module

In the 1.4.x.x it is working file but in the new it shows me this error... Can anyone please suggest me what I am supposed to do:

1) Either shift back from 1.5.x.x to 1.4.x.x.
2) If so, then suggest me the stable version

```
import {createContainer} from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import { Stus } from '../api/stus';
```

**APP.JSX**

```
export default class App extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={stus:[]};
}

App.propTypes={
stus: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};

export default createContainer(()=>
  {
      Meteor.subscribe('stus');
        return {
          stus: Stus.find({},{sort : {myname : 1} } ).fetch(),
        };

  },App);
```

Comment: I am more curious how did it work before.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should stick with the newer version and fix your code. You can't have 2 defaults. Also if you are not using `App` Component without the container created, you don't even need to export it

```
class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={stus:[]};
  }
}

export default createContainer(()=> { /* ... */ }, App);
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out your problem is exactly what the error message is. The javascript spec does not allow for more than one default export. After all, if you were importing the module, which would you expect to get?

If you want to export more than one thing, use named exports:

```
export const App = class App extends Component {};
export const myContainer = createContainer(() => {}, App);
```

Which can then be imported by name:

```
import { App, myContainer } from './myModule.js';
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'array' of undefined
    at App.jsx

Comment: It's just an example of what named exports and their respective imports look like. Not actual code to be run

Comment: Please have a look the new code which i.... written to solve my error...